# Matplotlib - error bars not centered on points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know it's been an issue before in matplotlib - but it should have been fixed, right?

When I exec. my example code for a scatter plot:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np


plt.xlabel(r'$Label \, in \, Latex$')
plt.ylabel(r'$Label \, in \, Latex$')
plt.title(r'$Title \, in \, Latex$')
#plt.text(1, 15, r'$Latex \, Example \, Text$')

x=[1, 2, 3, 4]
y=[1, 4, 9, 16]


plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=1, fmt='.k', capsize=3)
plt.savefig('foo.pdf', bbox_inches="tight")
```

the error bars are not centered on the points. I am using matplotlib 3.02 - Anaconda somehow doesn't recognize that there's 3.03.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the following work around: Specifying a `linewidth=1` for the error bar makes them centered. I tried several values and anything below 1.5 works centered but anything above 1.5 (inclusive) makes it shift off center. I do not know the reason. It could be related to the `dpi`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np

plt.xlabel(r'$Label \, in \, Latex$')
plt.ylabel(r'$Label \, in \, Latex$')
plt.title(r'$Title \, in \, Latex$')
#plt.text(1, 15, r'$Latex \, Example \, Text$')

x=[1, 2, 3, 4]
y=[1, 4, 9, 16]

plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=1, lw=1, fmt='.k', capsize=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Saving as `.svg` solves the issue for me. 
Using jupyter notebook the plot is shown with non-centered error bars but it is saved correctly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np

plt.xlabel(r'$Label \, in \, Latex$')
plt.ylabel(r'$Label \, in \, Latex$')
plt.title(r'$Title \, in \, Latex$')
#plt.text(1, 15, r'$Latex \, Example \, Text$')

x=[1, 2, 3, 4]
y=[1, 4, 9, 16]

plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=1, lw=2, fmt='o', capsize=3)

plt.savefig('TEST.svg', bbox_inches='tight', format='svg')
```